# Hiding border of dot density display in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I have a dot density symbology but I do not want to see the polygon borders. [Using dot density layers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-dot-density-layers.htm) makes it seem that ArcMap provided the ability to turn off the borders but I can't figure out how to in ArcGIS Pro.

Any ideas how to just show the dots, without the polygon borders?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the option to do this in ArcMap by following your link but there does not seem to be an equivalent option in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4:

[image]

Consequently, I think that you should post an idea for this to be added at [ArcGIS Ideas](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).

Answer (score 1):

This has since been enhanced. You can change the symbology for the polygon layer by changing the symbology from Background. It is detailed in the ArcGIS Pro documentation.

[https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/dot-density.htm][1]